# ASP.NET Core Scoped User instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I create a scoped instance for my API.
In the authentication and authorization parts I identify and set the userInfo (the information are coming from the sent API-Key and database behind...)

For the Auth part is seems to be working fine. But when the requested Controlled is at row I get a new instance, see log:

```
11 PostEntry; Username: guest; Session-ID: ca6f6b4d-dc4a-41d5-9ac7-d85c5215255d
10 Error-Controller-Constructor; Username: guest; Session-ID: ca6f6b4d-dc4a-41d5-9ac7-d85c5215255d
 9 AuthorizeAsync; Username: testuser; Session-ID: b7024903-26f5-47ee-bfc0-7b7a52adec71
 8 Username: testuser; ID: b7024903-26f5-47ee-bfc0-7b7a52adec71
 7 Return
 6 Start; Parameter[apiKey: 0330B900-0420-1337-ADCB-2DC70A89EEE3
 5 HandleAuthenticateAsync; Username: guest; Session-ID: b7024903-26f5-47ee-bfc0-7b7a52adec71
 4 Start; Username: guest; ID: b7024903-26f5-47ee-bfc0-7b7a52adec71
 3 AuthorizationService-Constructor; Username: guest; Session-ID: b7024903-26f5-47ee-bfc0-7b7a52adec71
 2 ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler; Username: guest; Session-ID: b7024903-26f5-47ee-bfc0-7b7a52adec71
 1 Username: guest; Session-ID: b7024903-26f5-47ee-bfc0-7b7a52adec71
```

From line 9 to 7 the userInfo object is set to the corresponding data. But when the controller is at row (line 11/10) there is a new instance, which can be seen by the new Session-ID. The session ID is set in the constructor of the object (`Guid.New()`).

Starup:

```
services.AddScoped<Identity.IUserInfo, Identity.UserInfo>();
```

Kind Regards

Comment: how many requests are you sending to the application?

Comment: Just one. With Postman.

Comment: What is a `Error-Controller-Constructor`?

Comment: The constructor of a controller called ErrorController :)

Comment: No one any any?